Why do particles need a signal to travel to another to affect it?
I was reading up on quantum entanglement, non locality, and how people interpret QM to still be local in the sense that it does not allow for faster than light communication signals.
I have two questions regarding this.
1.) If it doesn’t allow for FTL communication signals, doesn’t this automatically rule out deterministic theories that are said to violate this? If not, why are they not?
2.) Why do we need signals in the first place? If non locality is a real phenomenon of nature and one particle can instantly affect another at a completely different location, why would this need a signal to travel in between them? Isn’t this the very assumption non-locality, if true, violates? If it does violate it, then how does the no signalling theorem in physics disprove it?
From reading up more on this, it seems that one way physicists try to explain this is by saying that there is no “definite reality” out there. If there is none, then the correlations can remain. But if there is no “definite reality”, what exactly are we taking measurements of? Why are the measurements definite but not the state before measurement? What differentiates a measurement from a state before measurement if each of these happen due to the same underlying processes?
How do we have any experimental evidence of reality not being definite if every time we make measurements, we do get a definite result. It seems that postulating an undetectable, indefinite reality seems contrary to science, so I genuinely don’t understand how scientists are so sure about this. I also wonder if the very idea of an indefinite reality is incoherent (there can only be one reality at every moment, unless Everett is correct that all worlds happen!)
Note that I did cross post this on physics but the last few questions are arguably philosophical so I think it’s relevant here

hey, @Stella, check the comment https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5663/has-the-idea-of-splitting-the-philosophy-stackexchange-ever-been-discussed#comment9043_5691  :D

Nonlocality doesn’t mean there are FTL signals in spacetime. It means a local spacetime is inadequate to explain quantum correlations/experimental outcomes (excepting superdeterminism). We’ve looked for tachyons, FTL spacetime particles, and they aren’t there. Random or deterministic, it doesn’t matter-there is no FTL space time signaling because there are no tachyons. The nonlocality is not in spacetime. It’s in the wave function which is much higher dimensional than 4D spacetime. Nonlocality exists according to Bell’s theorem, which doesn’t say particles instantly affect one another.

We are still trying to figure out this extra-spacetime physics.

The straightforward answer today in relation to entangled particles is that there is no explicit signalling mechanism in the formalism of quantum theory. Indeed, QM is inherently non-local in the sense that if you have a particle with an extended wave function, and that particle undergoes some kind of interaction which causes the wave function to become more localised, then the standard Copenhagen interpretation is that the wave function changes instantly everywhere. Suppose I perform the stereotypical two slits experiment, firing electrons through the slits one at a time so they impinge upon a photographic plate. In principle the plate could be a parsec from the slits and several square parsecs in area, and in principle the electron wave function would expand through a correspondingly enormous volume of space, yet when the electron interacts with the plate to form a visible dot, the wave function becomes zero everywhere else with no time delay.

That assumes that the wave function is “real” though, correct? Some Copenhagen proponents propose that it does not actually match reality but is rather just an abstraction (instrumentalist). But this implies anti realism which I think has a whole host of issues

@Stella indeed, although you are wise to put 'real' in quotation marks because no one can agree what sort of 'reality' we are talking about when it comes to wave functions. But even if it is not real, it is the wave function alone that determines what happens, so if you have a two particle wave function, the so-called 'collapse' happens everywhere at once- there is no separate signal in QM that is exchanged between the particles to choreograph the collapse.


I was reading up on quantum entanglement, non locality, and how people interpret QM to still be local in the sense that it does not allow for faster than light communication signals.
I have two questions regarding this.
1.) If it doesn’t allow for FTL communication signals, doesn’t this automatically rule out deterministic theories that are said to violate this? If not, why are they not?
2.) Why do we need signals in the first place? If non locality is a real phenomenon of nature and one particle can instantly affect another at a completely different location, why would this need a signal to travel in between them? Isn’t this the very assumption non-locality, if true, violates? If it does violate it, then how does the no signalling theorem in physics disprove it?

Discussing this question properly requires stating how quantum theory makes predictions and how physicists talk about those predictions. The evolution of a measurable quantity in quantum theory is described by quantum observables A, B, C ... that are represented by Hermitian operators. The eigenvalues of those operators are the possible results of measuring the relevant physical quantity. The expectation value of a measurable quantity A is the sum of pi*Ai, where pi and Ai are the ith probability and possible value of A respectively. The expectation value of the observable in quantum theory is given by a rule called the Born rule that combines another operator called the state S with the observable.
Physicists agree that quantum mechanical equations plus the Born rule can be used to predict experimental results. They don't agree on what is happening in reality to bring those results about: this controversy is called the interpretation controversy. But this controversy isn't actually about interpreting quantum theory. There are three kinds of interpretations.
The first kind of interpretation states that you shouldn't try to explain the results of experiments and should instead just make predictions, e.g. - the Copenhagen and statistical interpretations. This has the notable defect that if you don't have anything to say about what's happening in reality, then there is no such thing as whether your experiment is set up correctly since saying a setup is correct requires that the portion of reality you're experimenting on has certain properties, e.g. - an atom has to actually be in a vacuum chamber in reality. So if you refuse to say anything about reality then there is no way to explain how to set up an experiment correctly let alone say anything about what the results mean. These theories say nothing about whether anything is local or non-local so they say your questions have no answers.
The second kind of interpretation changes quantum theory to make the resulting theory have some property like particles always having a single location. These theories include spontaneous collapse and pilot wave theories:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.10761
As explained in the paper above, these theories make different predictions than quantum theory. As a result calling them interpretations of quantum theory misrepresents both these theories and quantum theory.
The last category of interpretation is taking quantum theoretical equations of motion seriously as descriptions of reality and working out what they imply about how the world works. This is commonly called the Everett interpretation or the many worlds interpretation (MWI). In the MWI each system exists in multiple versions and we only see one at a time because when information is copied out of a system that prevents interference between different versions of the system in a process called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
This is confusing for people who try to learn or use quantum theory and this confusion has helped to lead to the idea that quantum theory is non-local.
The idea that quantum theory is non-local comes from a mathematical result called Bell's theorem. Bell's theorem sez that if you have a theory T in which a measurable quantity is described by a stochastic variable (a single number picked at random) and measurement devices aren't somehow correlated with what measurements you choose to make in advance, then in order to reproduce the predictions that quantum theory makes about entangled systems T must be non-local.
Some of the theories given above are in the same boat as theory T, such as the spontaneous collapse and pilot wave theories. The Copenhagen and statistical interpretations don't say anything about reality so their advocates have no clear statement to make about locality. The MWI describes measurable quantities using quantum mechanical observables which are not stochastic variables. Quantum mechanical equations of motion used to describe real systems are local so the evolution of the observables is local and they can be used to give a local account of entanglement experiments. The correlations between measurement results arise only when the results are brought together. Quantum information about the correlations is carried as locally inaccessible information in decoherent channels:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007
https://arxiv.org/abs/2304.14959
So the fact that there is a no communication theorem doesn't make the spontaneous collapse or pilot wave theories local, but the lack of communication is explained by the MWI because information is only transferred locally.
More generally there are theorems to the effect that any theory respecting no signalling has a local formulation:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01380

The true answer is easy to understand, but you'll have to pay attention.
Normally, to find the distance between two points x and y:

you add the x and y distances from the origin.1

In three dimensions you throw in the z distance. If one corner of a cube is at the origin, the distance to the opposite corner is:

Time is just another direction you can move in, like left-right, up-down, and forward-reverse. Everything with mass is always moving in the direction of future time at the speed of light.2
Side note: To convert an elapsed time into a space distance, multiply it by c. Hours times miles per hour equals miles.
Time is exactly like space, except for one (amazing) difference. This difference turns out to account for so many strange phenomena that I consider it the secret to the universe.
It's surprising nobody knows about it.
According to Einstein's spacetime pseudometric equation, when calculating the  4-dimensional, absolute3 distance between two events, the elapsed time between them is SUBTRACTED from the spatial distance between them:

Thus, since the moon is 1 light second away, when you feel the pull of the moon's gravity, you're interacting now with the actual moon in the past, one second ago.
So why did you just feel the gentle pull of the tide? Why didn't the moon from one second ago hit you in the head with moon
rocks?
Because points in the past are stretched out as they move into the future. This stretched-out object is called a "light cone."
But it only looks like a cone in 4 dimensions. To creatures living in 3 dimensions who are moving forward in time, any point event looks like an expanding sphere. This is why a pulse of light appears to be an expanding sphere.
In the case of mass, the expanding sphere is perceived as a gravity wave.
It's completely legitimate to think of the moon in the past as emitting a wave that catches up to you a second later. But  When you're thinking about space and time, it's simpler to see interaction as an encounter with an object in the past instead of a wave in the present.
SO WHAT DOES THIS HAVE TO DO WITH ENTANGLEMENT?
Well, notice that if the space distance between two events Is the same as the time distance, then the two events are on the same light cone and have an absolute distance of ZERO.
That's not the same thing as being in the same location. The objects are in two different locations at two different times. But when their space and time  distances are the same, their absolute 4D spacetime distance is zero.
A HINT ABOUT WHAT'S GOING ON: It's not often pointed out, but entangled particles always have the same distance from each other in space as they do in time. If they're separated by a light year, then their distance in time is one year. That would be the year it took light to cross the light-year.
Thus, spooky action at a distance isn't spooky, because the mysterious "communication" took an entire year to cross the distance. Every single quantum entanglement experiment involves taking time to separate the two objects.
It only seems spooky because it gives the illusion of superluminal communication. But that's not what's really happening.  The spin state, or whatever else you're measuring, is observed, not changed.
Another thing to notice: two photons are only entangled when they both were created at the same time at the same place.
The two photons are distinct, but exist at the same time (in your past).4 Their separation arises from the fact that they are in your past: If they were further in your past, their spatial separation would appear to be greater (they're photons moving at c).
A further hint, if you understand this so far, would be to observe that the only objects that can be entangled are moving apart at the speed of light.
Einstein didn't talk very much about the consequences of 4D distance being pseudometric, but it's all there in his equations. And it's responsible for just about all the crazy stuff in special relativity.
Time dilation and relativistic length contraction all seem perfectly normal and even expected when you truly appreciate that elapsed time is negative distance.
._______________________________________________
1Yes, yes, the squares of these values. Work with me here. Try to understand it, because it's true.
2Don't blame me. It's not my fault. Feynman said so in his 5th Australia lecture and his Easy Pieces book.
3Lorentz-invariant. Everyone agrees on the 4-dimensional distance (called an interval) between two events. It doesn't matter how fast they're moving or how fast the observer is moving.
4Both of them together are a single object called a null hypersurface. Black hole event horizons are also null hypersurfaces. Like photons, they don't experience the passage of time.

Your signs are backwards in eqn 3. ds^2 = cdt^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2

Did you not know that the two sign conventions for this equation are equivalent and switch back and forth depending on whether you're reading physics or mathematics? Or are you just trolling? === I use the  -+++ signature like Einstein did because it emphasizes that space distances are positive. You usually use that in special relativity. But the rest of science uses the opposite signature, for some reason. Apparently it's more convenient arithmetically.
